# Short story about meeting different intelligent species that have all evolved on Earth

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, prehistoric

Please help find a short story that deals with the following: Human time travellers go back to the time of the dinosaurs. I cannot remember if they encounter intelligent dinosaurs, but they do meet up with animals that have evolved intelligence throughout Earth's history (e.g. felines, some kind of quadruped~herbivore, amphibians). They are all surprised to encounter one another, thinking themselves the only intelligent species to have evolved on Earth because they existed for about 5~8 million years, and then were utterly obliterated from the fossil record by their own wars and the forces of time, until the next civilization arose about 10 million years later. I thought it might be "Wings of a Bat" by Ashwell, but cannot confirm this.

I thought this story may be part of the Robert Silverberg, Martin Harry Greenberg &  Charles G. Waugh anthology "Science Fictional Dinosaur" (1982), but unsure.

Comment: The various creatures were so surprised to meet one another because they existed for about 5~8 million years, and then were utterly obliterated from the fossil record by their own wars and the forces of time, until the next civilization arose about 10 million years later.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? This sounds like a good read.

Comment: Its definitely NOT "Wings Of A Bat" By Paul Ash/Pauline Ashwell: Only humans are intelligible in that one.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page](http://www.dinosaurcentral.com/what_kt_extinction.php) listing a bunch of intelligent dinosaur stories, the short story "Dinosaur on a Bicycle" by Tim Sullivan (publication history [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?189632), you might have read it in the anthology [*Dinosaurs!*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441148832) edited by Jack Dann and Gardner Dozois) has a description similar to the one you gave, although the different intelligent species are from alternate timelines rather than all arising in the same timeline and being obliterated from the fossil record:

> In an alternate universe where intelligent dinosaurs dominate the
> earth, a 19th-century dinosaur scientist sends his assistant back to
> the Cretaceous Era to visit their relatives. He meets up with a couple
> of time-traveling humans from another alternate universe and has some
> interesting adventures with the female after the man is eaten by a
> T-rex. They eventually discover a Nexus of Realities where they meet
> up with intelligent, time-traveling monkeys, raccoons, dogs, cats,
> lobsters, fish, cockroaches, rats, etc.